# create "virtual directory" with mounted device

Tags: filesystems, mount, directory

I need some help with my file system. I have an debian server running, which have an [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) instance installed. The server is running by an external provider as a virtual server. On this server, I have an HDD with 320 GB included.

So, I can use up to 300 GB for my nextcloud as storage space. The provider has some options to buy more space, but the problem is that the new space is like a mounted device.

Nextcloud is simply set up with a directory, where all data are stored (example "/var/local/nextcloud/data"). The problem is, that the new storage has a different directory path. So I only have the option to save all data at the mounted directory (but then I can't use the available 300 GB), or I mount the directory as external direcotry in my nextcloud (but so, every user has an extra folder showed up, and need to explicit save data in that folder, to store it on the extra mounted space).

Is there a way to combine two directories as one? I want to use my local 300 GB and the external storage combined, to point the storage folder at this directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, _AFAIK_ there's no easy way to unify two volumes so that they look like one directory. You could do that if you had both of the volumes managed by [`lvm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)), but I'm afraid it's not possible with the Nextcloud folder anyway. Maybe you could move something _else_ to the Nextcloud, to free up the primary space? Also note that a network-mounted space must have different performance characteristics than the local disk.